# auto refresh with blazor server

Tags: blazor-server-side

I am working on a Blazor Server web application.
I have an SQL Server Database and Entity Framework.

Look at this Entity:

```
public class Room
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public String name {get;set;}
   public DateTime closing_date {get;set;}
}
```

I want to display Room table content on a razor page:

```
<Virtualize Items="@rooms" Context="room">
    <table border="1">
    <tr @key=room.Id>
        <td>@room.Id</td>
        <td>@room.Name</td>
        <td>Closing in XXX minutes and YYY seconds</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</Virtualize>
```

As you can see, i don't want to display the closing date/time. I want to compute how many minutes are remaining before closing.

I can easily calculate XXX and YYY values. This is easy. What i want to do is to refresh values each seconds. How can i do that ?

In a classic web application i would create a javascript timer with setInterval for example. How can i do that in a blazor server project ?

Thanks

Comment: You could take a look at the timeago JS libraries. There are more than one. If that works it would be the most efficient way.

Comment: This library works with Blazor ?

Comment: I don't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Timer` class underneath the `System.Timers` namespace in order to accomplish this.

See the example [here](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/kir6txp3).

```
@code {
    private static System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private int counter = 60;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        StartTimer();
    }

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        _timer.Elapsed += CountDownTimer;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void CountDownTimer(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (counter > 0)
        {
            counter -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            _timer.Enabled = false;
        }

        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

You can combine this with something like [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) to easily get human-friendly formatting.

You'll want to make a component that is a `<tr>` element which conveniently I've [answered elsewhere...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67594373/simple-expandable-table-with-blazor/67596256#67596256)

Note that if you have thousands of these running per second, there are going to be some performance considerations. Whether that be reducing the refresh rate or continuing a Blazor Server solution over a JavaScript solution.

Comment: In my experience, Timers created in page creation events sometimes fail.  (like 1x out of 20).  I had to create a singleton service that broadcast a tick event instead.

Comment: Interesting. I’ve never run into that! I wonder if it is latency related between client and server?

Comment: I never found out.  I was actually using the timer to wait for a SVG animation to finish, and then display an "Enter Site" button.  Randomly (but on average about 10%-ish), the button would never display.  Users don't like having no way to get into your site, or so I'm told! :D    Anyway, among the async page methods, an async-context Timer, and the animation, Chrome  and / or Blazor and / or the VS debugger decided I was getting too fancy.

Comment: One thing I can say from your sample is that there may / may not be 2 timers spawned in the two runs through of OnInitialized.  Might lead to exciting results!

Comment: Depends if OP is using Prerendered or not.

Comment: The Timer should be Disposed and the StateHasChanged should be Invoked. @Bob5421: did this really work?

Answer (score 3):

Henk is correct in his comment that you have to Dispose the timer and Invoke StateHasChanged.  Here is the complete solution with those changes for .NET Core 6.

Razor component:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@implements IDisposable

<p>Time Remaining:  @_counter</p>

@code
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private int _counter = 60;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        _timer.Elapsed += CountDownTimer;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public async void CountDownTimer(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_counter > 0)
        {
            _counter -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            _timer.Enabled = false;
        }

        await InvokeAsync(async () =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And the code to use it on a Razor or MVC page assuming the component page is called "RoomTimer.razor".

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <component type="typeof(RoomTimer)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </div>
</div>  

@section scripts {
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
}
```