# Blazor Table with expandable rows

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I need to create a table (see [Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbJgq.png)) that contains multiple sections which are collapsable.
I found several pretty good frameworks (e.g., https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/pivot-table/getting-started). However, they are all costly.

Is there a way to create such a table without using an entire framework?

Unfortunately, I could not find any good blog, tutorial, or Github repo that implemented something like this without using a framework.
I had a look at question 67594373 ([Simple expandable table with Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67594373/15736989)). It is almost a similar problem. However, what this is missing are the symbols on the left side which show the collapse status. So I think they would also have to be updated when clicking a row. But I also think the entire structure of the table is not what I need.

I would be very thankful for any code or resource suggestions as this is very important.

Comment: Syncfusion has a [free community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/sales/faq/community-license?question=who-is-eligible?), you can use ALL of its components for free If you meet the requirements: _Individual developers or up to five users at companies with annual gross revenue below $1 million USD._. There are also open-source frameworks like [MudBlazor](https://mudblazor.com/) with the component you looking for. Otherwise, you can start from the example you provide from the question and customize it.

Comment: You should really give a visual sample of exactly what you want.  I can solve the issue of the collapsing arrows, but that's about as far as I can go with what you've said so far.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I added a sample how it should look like.

Comment: @Max thanks. MudBlazor looks really promising.

Comment: Okay, I have code that does exactly that.  The problem is that it doesn't play nice with SO.

Comment: With regard to Syncfusion, etc.  those frameworks are nice BUT-- about 50% of Blazor questions on SO are from frustrated users who can't get them to do what they want.  Be prepared to invest some time in really learning 3rd-party frameworks deeply if you go that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should give you a couple pointers I hope.  You need two main things:

1. A `bool` variable in the display class for each country (or whatever your main group is) to track whether it should display each city (or whatever your subgroup is);
2. Unicode characters for right-triangle, down-triangle.  You can find a LOT of symbols by just googling "unicode right arrow" or whatever.  I used the codes, but usually you can just copy the actual symbol that you find and paste it right into your markup, like this:  ▶ ▼

(I couldn't get the example to display properly in Stack Overflow code block due to the html `table` element, so please check the code in the following Blazor fiddle):

https://blazorfiddle.com/s/o7mk3izx

Here's a version using Bootstrap classes for the layout instead of tables:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">Region</div>
        <div class="col-3" >Sales</div>
    </div>
    @foreach (var country in Countries)
    {
        <div class="row" style="cursor:pointer;" @onclick="()=>country.ShowCities = !country.ShowCities">
            <div class="col-3">
                @if (!country.ShowCities)
                {
                    <span>&#x25b6;</span>
                }
                else
                {
                    <span>&#x25bc;</span>
                }
                &nbsp;@country.Name
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">@(AllCitySales.Where(acs=>acs.CountryID==country.ID).Sum(cs=>cs.Sales))</div>
        </div>
        if (country.ShowCities)
        {
            foreach (var city in AllCitySales.Where(acs => acs.CountryID == country.ID))
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8226;&nbsp;@city.Name</div>
                    <div class="col-3">@city.Sales</div>
                </div>
            }
        }
    }
</div>

@code {
    public class Country
    {
        public int? ID;
        public string? Name;
        public bool ShowCities;
    }
    public class CitySales
    {
        public int ID;
        public int CountryID;
        public string? Name;
        public int Sales;
    }
    public List<Country> Countries = new List<Country>
    {
        new Country{ ID = 1, Name="France"},
        new Country{ ID = 2, Name="England"}
    };
    public List<CitySales> AllCitySales = new List<CitySales>
    {
        new CitySales{ ID = 1, CountryID = 1, Name="Paris", Sales = 453},
        new CitySales{ ID = 2, CountryID = 1, Name="Marseille", Sales = 100},
        new CitySales{ ID = 3, CountryID = 2, Name="New York", Sales = 123},
        new CitySales{ ID = 4, CountryID = 2, Name="Los Angeles", Sales = 420},
        new CitySales{ ID = 5, CountryID = 2, Name="Scranton", Sales = 69}
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This snippet is really helpful.